# Scrapy logs in, but doesnt crawl anything

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

**Introduction**

My crawler finally manages to login, but it wont do any scraping and i cant find the reason for it.
My consoleoutput shows no error and i did a crawler for following every internal links some weeks ago, so i thought about, i just have to build my crawler almost identical, but yeah, here i am :>

My XPath expressions should be/have to be correct, because i started to "learn" crawling at this domain

I thought i have to choose `CrawlSpider` instead of `scrapy.Spider` but if i change my rules to `Linkextractor(r'/a-')` <-every productlink contains that "a-"-Tag, i get an error, so i tried to go without rules.

**My Code**

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from ..items import ScrapyloginItem

class TopartLoginIn(CrawlSpider):
    name = "test123"
    allowed_domains = ['topart-online.com']
    login_page = 'https://www.topart-online.com/de/Login/p-Login'
    start_urls = ['https://www.topart-online.com/']
    
    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(),
            callback='parse_page',
            follow=True
        ),
    )
    
    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(
            url=self.login_page,
            callback=self.login,
            dont_filter=True
        )
        
    def login(self, response):
        return FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={
                'ff_4d4d375f4c6f67696e5f55736572' : 'not real',
                'ff_4d4d375f4c6f67696e5f50617373' : 'login data',
                'ff_4d4d375f4c6f67696e' : ""                
            },
            callback=self.parse_page)
        
    def after_loging(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
        accview = response.xpath('//div[@class="myaccounticons row text-center"]')
        
        if accview:
            print('success')
            
        else:
            print(':(')
            
            for url in self.start_urls:
                yield Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_page)
                        
    def parse_page(self, response):
        productpage = response.xpath('//button[@class="btn btn-primary col-3 js-qty-up"]')

        for a in productpage:
            
            items = ScrapyloginItem()
            items['Title'] = response.xpath('//h1[@class="text-center text-md-left mt-0"]/text()').get()
            yield items
```

Here you can see, that the loginproccess is succeeded and also it calls, that the page i got referred to after login, i also no productlink. Thats exactly what i want, im just missing something, that it does the actual crawlprocess.
[image: consolge]

Comment: You should include the execution logs. By any change your spider prints `'success'` and stops there?

Comment: @renatodvc, yep exactly, i will upload a screenshot of my console

Answer (score 1):

From what you described, your spider log in, the `after_loging` method is called,
the var `accview` has some value, so it prints 'success' and it ends there because that's how your code is indented.

Notice that the new requests are only yielded if your `accview` var is empty.

```
def after_loging(self, response):
    open_in_browser(response)
    accview = response.xpath('//div[@class="myaccounticons row text-center"]')
    
    if accview:
        print('success')
        
    else:
        print(':(')
        
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_page)
```

You probably wanted something like this:

```
def after_loging(self, response):
    open_in_browser(response)
    accview = response.xpath('//div[@class="myaccounticons row text-center"]')
    if accview:
        print('success')
    else:
        print(':(')

    for url in self.start_urls:  # Notice the indentation here
        yield Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_page)
```

Comment: I see the difference, but it doesnt start following every link :/ im so frustrated because im stuck since today in the morning :( My Goal is that it visits every link, decides if its productlink or not, if yes it should start getting the information, i will set, yet i only set Title, but i cant get so far :(

Comment: i tested played a bit with my spider, now my problem is, that log in successfully or follow every link and parse it, but it wont do both together :/

Comment: Hi @y.y, you see, this is truncated information. It's hard to help you debug, because I can't see exactly what code you are running, what the execution logs prints and I also can't be sure of what you mean by "it wont do both together". That's why we usually ask that once the problem described in the question is addressed, you should open a new question, with all the mentioned details. Now, what do you mean it won't do both together? Is it skipping links? Skipping data? If raises a request it doesnt scrape? I really don't know.

Comment: hey @renatodvc, my problem is that, i can see in my console, that the login is successfully accomplished, but after that, it doenst do more. it only prints, that the "home"section of the homepage, is no productlink, but after it just stops. Normally i should follow the next link, check if its product link or not and so on

Comment: finally i managed to solve my problem ♥ thanks anyways :)